# Javascript hole in Firefox 16.0

Tags: javascript, exploit

Can someone explain me how this javascript hole works ??? :D
It's a hole that will gain data (the username) from a twitter window that will be opened...

```
alert('Hello '+/^https:\/\/twitter.com\/([^/]+)/.exec(win.location)[1])
```

Comment: What's `win`? (assuming it's `window`)

Comment: Why do you call it a hole, have you read that somewhere? If you have any reference, it will be good to understand your answer, otherwise, it's just a regex, as mentioned.

Comment: Since twitter accounts' URLs are just "http://www.twitter.com/USERNAME", it is a Regex (as others have mentioned) that extracts that value (the reason why it uses `[1]`)

Answer (score 1):

It's not an exploit, it's a very, very simple Regular Expression.

If you are currently on Twitter, that RegEx will compare your current address to `twitter.com/<USERNAME>/<...>` and pull out the `username` portion.

That is 100% *all* it does.

So if I'm at `https://twitter.com/nerdswguitars/`, the RegEx checks to see that I'm at `https://twitter.com/`, then it looks for ***every*** character after that which isn't another `/`, and collects them.

When it's done collecting them (ie: when it hits `/` or when it hits the end of the address you're at), it spits out the collected result.

```
var twitterRegEx = /https:\/\/twitter.com\/([^\/]+)/;
var twitterURL   = "https://twitter.com/nerdswguitars/";

// (...) collect whatever is in here, to return if it matches
// [ ]   compare against any of the characters inside
// [a-z] = compare against all lowercase letters in the English language
// [A-Z] = compare against all uppercase letters in the English language
// [_\-\*] = compare against "_" "-" and "*"
// [^...] = NOT -- compare against all characters NOT in this set
// so [^\/] = compare against any character that's NOT "/"
// + = 1 or more
// [^\/]+ = compare against one or more characters which are NOT "/"
// ([^\/]+) = collect every character which does not match "/"

var regExArray = twitterRegEx.exec(twitterURL); // ["https://twitter.com/nerdswguitars/", "nerdswguitars"]
var userName = regExArray && regExArray[1] || ""; // avoids an error - lots of ways to do this
```

The `exec` (or `match` if you want to do it the other way and use the string) process:

1. Find "https://twitter.com/" --> TRUE: continue on
2. Look at next character --> "n" !== "/" --> TRUE: collect it and continue on
3. Look at next character --> "e" !== "/" --> TRUE: collect it and continue on
4. Look at next character --> "r" !== "/" --> TRUE: collect it and continue on

13.Look at next character --> "s" !== "/" --> TRUE: collect it and continue on
14.Look at next character --> "/" !== "/" --> FALSE: return all of the collected letters

PS: your code there causes a serious issue if you're not careful.
If a RegEx fails (like if there is no match at all), instead of returning an array, it returns `null`.
If you try `null[1];` JS gets angry at you and throws an error.